# Midpoints of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

The points $(4,2), (-1,-3)$, and $(-10,6)$ are the midpoints of the sides of triangle $ABC$. What is the area of triangle $ABC$?

Comment: I've found the points of the triangle: (13,-7), (-5,11), (-15,1).

Comment: Yes - what else?

Comment: Compute the area of the triangle whose vertices are the given three points and multiply by four. (Draw a picture of $\Delta ABC$ and connect the midpoints of the sides, partitioning this triangle into four congruent pieces.)

Comment: Should I use the distance formula to find the sides?

Comment: @Ari: you can use Determinant formula for area. http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheAreaOfATriangleUsingADeterminant/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The slope between $(4,2)$ and $(-1,-3)$ is 1. The slope between $(-1, -3)$ and $(-10, 6)$ is -1. Hence these two lines are perpendicular, and so we have a right triangle.

**Hint:** Find the area of the triangle.

**Hint:** Show that the median triangle is similar to the original triangle. What is the ratio?

**Hint:** Show that the area of the median triangle is $\frac{1}{4}$ the area of the original triangle.

---

Another approach: You have found the 3 vertices of the triangle. Show that 2 of those lines are perpendicular, and hence you have a right triangle. This makes it easy to find the area.

The reason why this works is motivated by the above.

Comment: What can the OP do if (s)he ever faces triangles that aren't right-angled?Just thought that this should be mentioned.

Comment: @rah4927 That would depend on the context in which OP received this question. Most of the time, Heron's isn't taught in school, which make make resorting to Heron's useless. I would prefer doing the shoelace formula, or even the "large rectangle minus several triangles" approach.

Comment: I tried the "large rectangle minus 3 triangles" method and got 180, which I believe is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Though computation intensive, you might want to check out Heron's formula now that you have the points.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_Formula

Your task now is to find the side lengths from the given points!

Comment: Heron's is overkill in this situation.

Comment: No doubt!  However, it never hurts to know a wide range of methods for calculating the area of a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Area of the whoole triangle is $4A$  where $A$ is the area of the triangle of midpoints.(triangle are similiar with ratio $2$) and

$$A={1\over 2}|det( \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & 1 \\-1 & -3 & 1\\-10 & 6 & 1  \end{bmatrix}\quad|)=45$$

Thus, area of the big triangle is $4x45=180$

Instead of Heron Formula, determinant formula is more useful in analitic geometry.

If $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)$ are the points then

$$A={1\over 2}|det( \begin{bmatrix} a & b & 1 \\c & d & 1\\e & f & 1  \end{bmatrix}\quad|)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 1)Find the area of the medial triangle.

```
           2)What is the ratio of areas of the original triangle to the medial triangle?
```